# Question regarding Neel temperature for antiferromagnetic material

Tags: magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, material-science

I am doing an experiment, where I find that the neel temperature (AFM - PM transition) of a sample is increasing with increase in the magnetic field. Although I tried to find an explanation, I could not find literature on this. I found literature where at low temperatures, there is onset of ferromagnetism in the system as some of the dipoles align with the applied magnetic field and lead to ferromagnetic (FM) behavior.(Please correct me if I am wrong). At room temperature, I observed this change in neel's temperature. How I explained this is that in presence of magnetic field, there is ordering in the system and thus, the thermal agitations need to overcome this ordering to make the transition from AFM to PM. Although, a professor of mine said that neels temperature is independent of magnetic field, and AFM would vanish at neels temperature that was for 0 applied magnetic field case.

Details:
Sample: Chromium.

Magnetic field: 2200 Gauss

Change in neels temperature: 38 degrees to 40 degrees celcius

Can someone please give me a bit more literature on this?

Comment: Surely that should be ferrimagnetic rather than ferromagnetic. It seems like your professor is trying to assert that the definition of the Néel temperature is only for the zero magnetic field case; whatever you have observed is still real physics, just that it is not called an increase in Néel temperature. Sounds like a disagreement in semantics and not physically interesting, and surely not as interesting as the experimental result you are seeing.

Comment: Hello@naturallyInconsistent, Sorry, I don't understand your last statement, " Sounds like a disagreement in semantics and not physically interesting, and surely not as interesting as the experimental result you are seeing". 
Thanks for the remarks and also, yes its ferrimagnetic.

Comment: I was trying to say that your professor's point about Néel temperature being for zero magnetic field is just semantics and really nowhere near as interesting as your observation that converting from AFM behaviour to PM behaviour occurs at higher temperature as externally applied B field increases.